# Category tree not showing on admin's product edit page?

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0

I have a store in magento c.e 1.8 i have created categories but the category tree is not not showing up on product edit section.

I can see the categories in Manage Categories section.

Please help if someone know about this problem.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Check the response of the ajax request made when you click on the "Categories" tab.

Comment: might be a cache issue, have you flushed the cache

Answer (score 3):

This Fix the issue (for me):

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET children_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity) AS table2 WHERE path LIKE CONCAT(catalog_category_entity.path,"/%"));
```

Make a backup before execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the very same problem 
checking the database we have the level category's attribute with a wrong value.

I solved running the query founds on this link

[Solving problems with Category tree database information](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/solving-problems-with-category-tree-database-information/)

hope this helps other